# Combine output from two Jobs

Tags: powershell

I have a Windows command line utility which outputs text to standard output, as well as logging to a file. The two outputs complement each other, and so I want to be able combine both streams. The standard output will remain untouched. However, I aim to take chunks of the log file, process them, and also send it to standard output.

My first attempt was to run:

```
[HashTable] $queue = @{};

$roboDealerJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Param(
        [string] $outputFile,
        [HashTable] $queue
    )
    & "utility.exe" $outputFile |
    ForEach-Object
    {
        $queue.Add($_, $_);
    }
} -Name "MyUtility" -ArgumentList $outputFile,$queue;

While (!(Test-Path $logFile))
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
}

Get-Content -Path $logFile -Tail 1 -Wait |
ForEach-Object {
    Receive-Job $roboDealerJob
    ForEach ($item in $queue.Values)
    {
        Write-Host $item;
        $queue.Remove($item);
    }
    Write-Host $_;
}
```

However, the job doesn't seem to run.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: `Start-Job` run in separate PowerShell process. It does not have access to `$queue` variable. It just copy `-ArgumentList` values when job start, but them not linked to original object, them just a copies.